# Using web-mode "localized" in babel

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-babel

I am using org-mode babel to take notes. I am using source code blocks to write down examples of html interspersed with javascript. I take the notes in a subtree within a pretty big document.

Now, when I edit the source code block I would like to use web mode to have automatic indentation and auto-complete etc. However, somewhere in the document is an unmatched expression, so web-mode will complain. There is no way I will find the unmatched expression (or want to actually).

Is there a way to use web-mode localized so to speak, e.g. only within the source code block? Or could I actually configure org-mode to automatically recognize the language of the source code block and switch modes accordingly w/o having to change manually?

Comment: Try `C-c '` (`org-edit-special`).

Comment: No, same issue. 'search failed: there is an unmatched expression....' So it seems that org-edit-special takes the whole document as scope